# Firefox doesn't show custom error messages

Tags: javascript, firefox, exception, coffeescript, console

I'm trying to create an extendable error class in CoffeeScript with this code:

```
class @ExtendableError extends Error
  constructor: (message = '') ->
    super message

    Object.defineProperty @, 'message',
      configurable: true
      enumerable : false
      value : message
      writable : true

    Object.defineProperty @, 'name',
      configurable: true
      enumerable : false
      value : @.constructor.name
      writable : true

    Object.defineProperty @, 'stack',
      configurable: true
      enumerable : false
      value : (new Error(message)).stack
      writable : true
```

When I try to throw one of these errors in Firefox using this code:

```
throw new ExtendableError('An error message');
```

I only get `[object Object]` printed to the console.

When I throw a built in error:

```
throw new Error('An error message');
```

I get the desired error message printed to the console: `Error: An error message`.

It should be noted that both, `Error.toString()` and `ExtendableError.toString()` work correctly. So I have absolutely no clue what's going on.

I tested the same code in Chrome without problems and I've literally searched for ours in Google without luck.

Any ideas?

## Update 1:

Someone asked me to include the generated JavaScript code. So here it is:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.10.0
(function() {
  var extend = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; },
    hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

  this.ExtendableError = (function(superClass) {
    extend(ExtendableError, superClass);

    function ExtendableError(message) {
      if (message == null) {
        message = '';
      }
      ExtendableError.__super__.constructor.call(this, message);
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'message', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        value: message,
        writable: true
      });
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        value: this.constructor.name,
        writable: true
      });
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'stack', {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        value: (new Error(message)).stack,
        writable: true
      });
    }

    return ExtendableError;

  })(Error);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

I put your file in *lib/Error.coffee*. Then I converted to Javascript:

```
 coffee --compile --output dist lib
```

It created the file *dist/Error.js*.

Then I ran your code with this simple page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
   <script src="dist/Error.js"></script>
   <script>
     throw new ExtendableError('example error');
   </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I did some test with Firefox 46.0.1 in Linux and I didn't find any problem, look my screenshoots:

### Firefox with Inspect Element

[image: Firefox inspect Element]

### Firefox with Firebug

[image: Firefox with Firebug]

### Chrome

It very similar in Chrome.
[image: Chrome Example]

I guess the problem is in another part of your code, maybe you're catching the exception and you're doing something with it.

If the problem persist in your Firefox installation and your think it is related with the version of the browser, you can use [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/) to test your code with many different versions of the browser and many different Operative System.

Comment: Can you try to throw the error from Firefox's console. Now I'm thinking this error only appears when throwing subclasses of Error from the console. I'll try to replicate your results too.

Comment: I run in the console "throw new ExtendableError('foo');" and it has a similar output in Firebug, but in the "Inspect Element" appear [object Object], like you said

Comment: It is the fault of the "Inspect Element" of firefox, I will investigate

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code written in ES6 to make extendable Errors, and it works on Chrome, Firefox and Opera.

`` class CustomError extends Error{
    constructor(msg){
        super();
        console.log(`CustomError: ${msg}`);
    }
} ``

So i think the problem is how coffeescript is compiling your code.